# Is there a fade in horizontally function for text in Flutter?

Tags: animation, flutter, dart

I have a game which asks new question when user answers correctly the previous one. What I want to do is when the new question comes to screen I want it to fade in horizontally from left to right. Is there animation in flutter?

It would be excellent if that animation fade the question line by line (fade first line of question left to right and then when finish it do the same for the other lines, so that it looks likes it is being written right now letter by letter).

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this package of flutter  : `marquee 1.3.1`

Install :

```
dependencies:
  marquee: ^1.3.1
```

then use in class like this :

```
Marquee(
  text: 'There once was a boy who told this story about a boy: "',
)
```

for more info try out this : [marquee](https://pub.dev/packages/marquee#-installing-tab-)